# Mysql: Trouble with slow query with big Text Type field

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table with over 150k rows. One column in the table have a "text" Type. This field contain text of over 50k characters. Thats means that I have 150k block of text with over 50k characters stored in that column.

The text is the HTML source of different web pages. Because of that, I cannot use a varchar type since I need to keep the linebreak.

When doing query where this column is selected or in the WHERE clause, the query is really slow and take forever to complete.

For example, doing a simple query starting with:

```
SELECT my_text_column FROM my_table LIMIT 1000
```

take more than 30 secondes. 30 secondes for 1/150 of the table, thats real bad.

I tried adding an INDEX to this column but I cant seem to be able to add an INDEX to a text type column.

What can I do to optimize this column and make sure that all my queries will go fast?

EDIT:

The complete table structure is`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `my_table` (
  `url_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `url` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `source` text NOT NULL,
  `completed` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`url_id`),
  KEY `completed` (`completed`),
  KEY `url` (`url`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=150775 ;
```

Comment: The problem might not really be the `TEXT` column.  Please post the structure of the table.  You should almost never use a normal index on a `TEXT` column.

Comment: @G-Nugget: Table structure added.

Comment: Your structure mentions that the `PRIMARY KEY` is on `primary_key`, but that column doesn't exist.  Is that a typo?  Since you're using InnoDB, your buffer might be too small.  In the sample query, would you normally have a `WHERE` clause?  If you're using the text column in the `WHERE` clause that will definitely slow down the query.

Comment: @G-Nugget: Yes, typo, sorry corrected. In the sample query I wont normally have a WHERE clause. A plain basic query takes ton of time.

Comment: In PHPMyAdmin, go to the status tab and check the adviser section.  That may provide you with some help.

Answer (score 0):

If your column values are at least 50K, then the query you posted will retrieve a 50M result set.  If that's the case, it's not surprising that it takes a long time.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried a full text index? Slightly different to normal index. Plenty examples on msdn